# NodeJS and Gulp throws an error

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I am having a problem when I try to run Gulp watch.

Here's the error being thrown:

```
[15:42:57] Using gulpfile ~/bartslaw-nyc/Gulpfile.js
[15:42:57] Starting 'browserSync'...
[15:42:57] Finished 'browserSync' after 17 ms
[15:42:57] Starting 'clean'...
[15:42:57] Finished 'clean' after 5.25 ms
[15:42:57] Starting 'pages'...
[15:42:57] 'pages' errored after 6.59 ms
[15:42:57] TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at flattenGlob (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/node_modules/glob2base/index.js:9:25)
    at setToBase (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/node_modules/glob2base/index.js:48:12)
    at module.exports (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/node_modules/glob2base/index.js:56:19)
    at Object.gs.createStream (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:34:42)
    at Object.gs.create (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:68:42)
    at Gulp.src (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/index.js:33:23)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/Gulpfile.js:44:15)
    at module.exports (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/k7/bartslaw-nyc/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
[BS] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.3:3000
 ------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.3:3001
 ------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: _build
```

The issue is that on my browser there's just "Cannot GET /". Help me out on this one. This seems to have happened all of a sudden.

I have a repository on Bitbucket from where I pulled the initiate source files (this repository is created and maintained by me).

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance. Do let me know if you need to see the gulp.config and gulpfile.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: there's a newly opened bug ticket in the gulp repo, you may wish to follow it https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1768

Answer (score 0):

i think its happening because of an npm package update where the version number was not bumped

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there has an issue right now. You can follow the discussion below:
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1768

Comment: The issue was fixed a few minutes ago; you can try again later.